# EF Core foreign key - mark dependent entity as required

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EF Core, I manually configured navigation properties between a database view and a table. Here are the table and view.

**Dealer Table**

| DealerId | DealerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dealer One |

**PhysicalAddress View**

| DealerId | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | City one |

They are configured via the fluent api like so:

**Dealer**

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>(entity =>
 {
     entity.ToTable("Dealer");

     entity.Property(e => e.DealerId)
         .ValueGeneratedNever()
         .HasColumnName("Dealer_Id");

    entity.Property(e => e.DealerName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(70)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasColumnName("Dealer_Name");
});
```

**PhysicalAddress**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PhysicalAddress>(entity =>
{
     entity.HasKey("DealerId");

     entity.ToView("PhysicalAddress");

     entity.Property(e => e.DealerId).HasColumnName("Dealer_Id");

    entity.Property(e => e.City)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasColumnName("City");

     entity.HasOne(e => e.Dealer)
        .WithOne(d => d.PhysicalAddress)
        .HasForeignKey<PhysicalAddress>(e => e.DealerId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
});
```

And the PhysicalAddress class:

```
public partial class PhysicalAddress
{
    public int DealerId { get; set; }       
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
}
```

In my application code, I am using the foreign key to check if PhysicalAddress is a required dependent of Dealer. Note, this is a simplified version of my actual app code in which the types aren't hard-coded.

```
private bool IsPhysicalAddressRequired()
{
    IEntityType dealerEntType = GetDealerEntityType();
    INavigation nav = baseType.FindNavigation(prop);
    IForeignKey fk = nav.ForeignKey;

    if (fk.IsRequired)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method returns false.

**My question:**

How do I configure the relationship between Dealer and PhysicalAddress so PhysicalAddress is a required dependent of Dealer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. To make PhysicalAddress a required dependent of Dealer, it was set was set as an owned entity. This was done in a partial class of the DbContext:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.OwnsOne(e => e.PhysicalAddress, b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("PhysicalAddress");

                entity.Property(e => e.City)
                  .IsRequired()
                  .HasMaxLength(50)
                  .IsUnicode(false)
                  .HasColumnName("City");

                b.Property(pa => pa.DealerId).HasColumnName("Dealer_Id").IsRequired();

            });

            entity.Navigation(e => e.PhysicalAddress).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Finally, in the DbContext file generated by Entity Framework, OnModelCreatingPartial must be called at the end of OnModelCreating:

```
public partial class GMDIContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // EF generated entity configurations here

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```